# TSQL performance with @@Error and Can they be replaced ?

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I have inherited code that looks like this:

**Stored Procedure UpdateSomeStuff**

```sql
Update Table1 Set Col1=Para@1

IF @@Error > 0 Goto ERR

Update Table2 Set Col1=Para@2

IF @@Error > 0 Goto ERR

RETURN 0

ERR:

return  -1;
```

This sp is called by ADO.NET in c# like this

```
try
{
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    _log.Error(ex);
    throw();
}
finally
{
    if(myConnection!=null)
    {
            myConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

I am just asking myself: Is the part **IF @@Error > 0 Goto ERR** good for anything? If an error happens the sp would return anyway and an exception would be caught in the calling method.

The calling code does not handle the return value 0 and -1. My plan would be to remove all Errorhandling in the Stored Procedure an have the same result. Am I right or is there something I missed?

Comment: No, if there is an error, the remaining statements of the SP will still execute. If the intention is to NOT continue execution of the remaining T-SQL, you have to keep the error checks in place. But I'm surprised there are no transactions involved in the original SP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My '2 cents' you will kill the performance by removing if@error statements.
so either you implement try catch as mitch says or do not remove them.
 Just think if there is error at first statement then it will not attempt to execute 2nd statement and so on when you have if@error statements.

and if you remove them , sql server is going to try next statement until it reaches the limit when it decides it can not go ahead with further processing.

Answer (score 7):

A better approach (SQL Server 2005 onwards) is to use [`TRY..CATCH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx):

```sql
BEGIN TRY
    -- Perform operations here
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH
```

A good reference is: [Error Handling in SQL 2005 and Later](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling_2005.html)

Comment: Will this still run into the catch block of the calling method? Because that is what I need.

Comment: If you raise an error if your stored procedure, it can be caught by the calling C# code's catch block.